# flutter dynamic device identifier

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building a Flutter app and need an unique id each device but the id have to regenerate/refresh every time user clear data/reinstall. I already use [device_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus) but in only works for IOS only (using `identifierForVendor`). How to get this behavior for Android?

Thanks all.

Comment: You can use [flutter_udid](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_udid) to get a unique ID for the device, but if you need the ID to be refreshed every time the app is reinstalled, why not just generate and cache a [uuid](https://pub.dev/packages/uuid)?

Comment: actually I tried to avoid using cached. flutter_id always give consistent id even after reinstalling the app.

Comment: That's because using a package like `device_info_plus` and `flutter_udid` don't give you a random ID. They give you the persistent ID of the app and/or the device, and that's not going to change between installs. If you need a truly random unique ID for every install, `uuid`, [`nanoid`](https://pub.dev/packages/nanoid), or some other similar random ID generator is what you want, and because it's an ephemeral ID, you will need to cache it after you generate it or it will reset every time the app starts up. (You have many options on *where and how* you cache it, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

Due to android developer policy you can't generate unique device ID or IMEI. After android version 10, android disable that for user privacy. But you can do with FUID or generate yourself for uniqueID.
Please read in here. >>> https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids . I also use FUID(Firebase unique id) for all my project.

Comment: Android 10 added limitations for *non-resettable hardware IDs", not unique device IDs in general. You can use software-derived unique IDs like [`Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure#ANDROID_ID) just fine on modern Android versions.

Comment: Thanks for more fixing and more detail.